# Create a new DataFrame from two existing DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a pandas rookie and I have reviewed similar questions in stackoverflow, but this seems unique.

I am looking for a function that will compare A and B and if any column in B has a value > 0 for the column, the DataFrame B will be used to create DataFrame C.

The goal is for DataFrame C the same size as DataFrame A, just with DataFrame B's values for the columns with the same label.

```
Have: 
A = pd.DataFrame({"X1": [0], "Y1": [0], "X2": [0], "Y2": [0], "X3": [0], "Y3": [0], "X4": [0], "Y4": [0]})

B = pd.DataFrame({"X1": [9], "Y1": [99.9]})

Want:

C= pd.DataFrame({"X1": [9], "Y1": [99.9], "X2": [0], "Y2": [0], "X3": [0], "Y3": [0], "X4": [0], "Y4": [0]})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: So will DataFrame A always have only 0 as values, as your example seems to suggest ?

Comment: Can `B` contain keys not in `A`? Can you just `for b in B:` or would that have illegal values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) where B > 0:

```py
C = A.copy()
C.update(B.where(B>0))
```

Output:

```
   X1    Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3  X4  Y4
0   9  99.9   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: That's a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but is seems a bit forced

```
import pandas as pd


A = pd.DataFrame({"X1": [0], "Y1": [0], "X2": [0], "Y2": [
                 0], "X3": [0], "Y3": [0], "X4": [0], "Y4": [0]})

B = pd.DataFrame({"X1": [9], "Y1": [99.9]})

C = pd.concat([A, B])

D = C.fillna(0)

E = D.iloc[1:]

print (E)
```

Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little ugly but it gets the job done

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"X1": [0], "Y1": [0], "X2": [0], "Y2": [0], "X3": [0], "Y3": [0], "X4": [0], "Y4": [0]})
B = pd.DataFrame({"X1": [9], "Y1": [99.9]})

B = B.loc[:, (B > 0).any(axis=0)]
cols = B.columns.tolist()
C = A
C[cols] = B[cols]
```

Comment: Here, you're also changing the values of `A` by reference. I'd create `C` as a copy of `A`.

Comment: Good point agreed, I prefer your solution anyways :)